# What is distribution of Poisson multiplied by positive constant

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ is poisson distribution.

$$f_{X}(n;\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$

And there is some positive constant $\alpha$.

I like to know pmf(probability mass function) of $Z=\alpha X$.

I have searched this topic and i could find almost similar [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35042/what-is-the-distribution-of-an-average-of-poisson-random-variables).

This post deal with distribution of $Y=\frac{X}{m}$ ($X$ is poisson and $m$ is constant).

But it is not easy to understand to me.

Especially calculating pgf(probability generating function) of $Y$ part!

What is $D_{m,t}p(x)$?

Please explain more detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $P(X=n) = \dfrac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$ when $n$ is a non-negative integer and $0$ otherwise, and $Z=\alpha X$ then $$P(Z=z)=\dfrac{\lambda^{z / \alpha}}{(z/\alpha)!}e^{-\lambda}$$ when $z/\alpha$ is a non-negative integer and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Can i know derivation of this result? Is it possible calculate (z/$\alpha$)!?According to my memory, $Z$ is not a poisson. Thank you

Comment: @Kim: The derivation comes from a simple substitution $n=z/\alpha$, so it is easy to calculate $(z/\alpha)!$ when $z/\alpha$ is a non-negative integer. You are correct, saying $Z$ is not Poisson, if $\alpha \not =1$. For example $E[Z]=\alpha \lambda \not = \alpha^2 \lambda = \text{var}(Z) $

Comment: This distribution has a name?

Comment: @becko I doubt it, though calling it a "scaled Poisson distribution" would probably work