# There is problem in calculating pgf(probability generating function)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I posted question about distribution of poisson distribution multiplied by constant.
[Here!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640151/what-is-distribution-of-poisson-multiplied-by-positive-constant)

From this post, i can obtain what i want.

$$P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$
$$Z=\alpha X (\alpha>0)$$
$$P(Z=z)=\frac{\lambda^{z/\alpha}}{(z/\alpha)!}e^{-\lambda}$$
And i tried to calculate pgf of this distribution like below.

$$G_{z}(t)=E[t^{Z}]=\sum_{z}t^{z}\frac{\lambda^{z/\alpha}}{(z/\alpha)!}e^{-\lambda}(z=0,\alpha,2\alpha,3\alpha,......)$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{z}t^{z}\frac{\lambda^{z/\alpha}}{(z/\alpha)!}e^{-\lambda}$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}(1+t^{\alpha}\lambda+t^{2\alpha}\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2!}+....)$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}e^{t^{\alpha}\lambda}=e^{\lambda(t^{\alpha}-1)}$$

To check pgf, i use $P(Z=z)=\frac{G^{z}_{Z}(0)}{z!}$ formula.
But probability is zero except $P(Z=0)$.

Where did i mistake?

Comment: PGF is well defined for nonnegative, integer valued random variables. $Z$ is not such r.v. in general. So you can find Laplace transform or characteristic function of $Z$.

Comment: Oh sorry i omit the fact $\alpha$ is positive integer!

Comment: OK. And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right pgf, though you could get there easier:

$$G_Z(t) = E(t^Z) = E\left(t^{\alpha X}\right) = E\left(\left(t^\alpha\right)^X\right) = G_X\left(t^\alpha\right) = e^{\lambda\left(t^{\alpha}-1\right)}$$

since $X\sim$ Poisson$(\lambda)$ so we know that $G_X\left(t\right) = e^{\lambda\left(t-1\right)}$.

In checking its validity, perhaps you are differentiating incorrectly. To find $P(Z=\alpha)$, for example,

\begin{align}
G_Z^{'}(t) &= e^{\lambda\left(t^{\alpha}-1\right)} \left[ \lambda\alpha t^{\alpha-1} \right] \\
G_Z^{''}(t) &= e^{\lambda\left(t^{\alpha}-1\right)} \left[ \lambda\alpha(\alpha-1) t^{\alpha-2} + \lambda^2\alpha^2 t^{2\alpha-2} \right] \\
& \ldots \\
G_Z^{(\alpha)}(t) &= e^{\lambda\left(t^{\alpha}-1\right)} \left[ \lambda\alpha! t^{0} + \text{terms containing $t$} \right] \\
& \\
\therefore\quad P(Z=\alpha) &= \dfrac{G_Z^{(\alpha)}(0)}{\alpha!} = 
\dfrac{e^{-\lambda} (\lambda\alpha!)}{\alpha!} = \lambda e^{-\lambda}.
\end{align}